# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'negate'

Tags: python-3.x, django, mongodb, mongoengine, djongo

I'm getting the error when trying to get all the Urls for which the limited field is True. I've tried deleting the migrations and creating new migrations, but still getting the same error.

these are the installed dependencies:

- asgiref==3.4.1
- backports.zoneinfo==0.2.1
- Django==4.0
- django-cors-headers==3.10.1
- django-shell-plus==1.1.7
- djangorestframework==3.13.1
- djongo==1.3.6
- dnspython==2.1.0
- gunicorn==20.1.0
- pymongo==3.12.1
- python-dotenv==0.19.2
- pytz==2021.3
- sqlparse==0.2.4
- tzdata==2021.5

models.py:

```
class Urls(models.Model):
    _id = models.ObjectIdField()
    record_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    hash = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=1000)
    long_url = models.URLField()
    created_at = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    expires_in = models.DurationField(default=timedelta(days=365*3))
    expires_on = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    limited = models.BooleanField()
    exhausted = models.BooleanField()
```

query:

Urls.objects.filter(limited=False)

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 857, in parse
    return handler(self, statement)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 933, in _select
    return SelectQuery(self.db, self.connection_properties, sm, self._params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 116, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 152, in parse
    self.where = WhereConverter(self, statement)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 27, in __init__
    self.parse()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/converters.py", line 119, in parse
    self.op = WhereOp(
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 476, in __init__
    self.evaluate()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 465, in evaluate
    op.evaluate()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/operators.py", line 258, in evaluate
    self.rhs.negate()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'negate'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 51, in execute
    self.result = Query(
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 784, in __init__
    self._query = self.parse()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/sql2mongo/query.py", line 885, in parse
    raise exe from e
djongo.exceptions.SQLDecodeError:

        Keyword: None
        Sub SQL: None
        FAILED SQL: SELECT "short_urls"."_id", "short_urls"."record_id", "short_urls"."hash", "short_urls"."long_url", "short_urls"."created_at", "short_urls"."expires_in", "short_urls"."expires_on", "short_urls"."limited", "short_urls"."exhausted" FROM "short_urls" WHERE NOT "short_urls"."limited" LIMIT 21
        Params: ()
        Version: 1.3.6

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
djongo.database.DatabaseError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 256, in __repr__
    data = list(self[:REPR_OUTPUT_SIZE + 1])
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 262, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1354, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 51, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1202, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/mnt/c/Users/pranjal/Desktop/urlhash/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/djongo/cursor.py", line 59, in execute
    raise db_exe from e
django.db.utils.DatabaseError
```

Comment: you have written limited= False

Comment: It should be Urls.objects.all().filter(limitted = True)

Comment: Question, @RitankarBhattacharjee, woudn't `Urls.objects.all().filter(limited=True)` be the same as `Urls.objects.filter(limited=True)`?  But I agree, the question does state the query is opposite to what the OP wrote in the query.

Comment: @R.Uziel, Yes Yes, this is the same actually I am habituated of writing .all(), but mainly i pointed out that limitted sould be equal True

Answer (score 1):

I would need to see your views.py where you do that query, `Urls.objects.filter(limited=False)` but first, perhaps the query is not finding any Urls objects that match the criteria, limited=False, thus the query returns None, which has no attributes.  Second, I'm not familiar with negate.  I don't see it in your model.  Perhaps if I see the views.py where you make that query I will understand better.

Comment: exactly, views.py will make it clear from where the negate is comming